# Getting an [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] in Sumo Logic, unable to find what is causing the issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, http-headers

I am getting an [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] error in sumologic and before this error, I can see three different file names, in those files, I can't find what is causing this error. Here are the functions which were listed in sumologic logs before the error.

In this function, it is shown at the last cb(null, true)

```
let sendEvent = function (req, payload, cb) {
  if (process.env.NODE_LOCAL === 'true' && !process.env.DEBUG) {
    req.mtShout.debug('No QUEUE Submission because this is local ENV');
    return cb(null, true);
  }

  sqs.getQueueUrl({QueueName: awsConfig.queueName}, function(e, d){
    if (e) {
      req.mtShout.error("Error when putting RA message onto SQS: ", e);

      e = new Error("Failed to put RA event onto SQS queue");
      cb(e, null);
    } else {
      sqs.sendMessage({
        MessageBody: JSON.stringify(payload),
        QueueUrl: d.QueueUrl
      }, function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
          req.mtShout.error("Error when putting RA message onto SQS: ", err);

          err = new Error("Failed to put RA event onto SQS queue");
          cb(err, null);
        } else {
          req.mtShout.debug('Successfully queued ' + payload.event_name + ' RA event', data);
          cb(null, true);
        }
      });
    }
  });
};
```

In this function, it is shown at return cb()

```
awsService.sendEvent(req, payload, function(err, resp) {
    if (err) {
      if (tries <= 3) {
        tries++;
        return sendEvent(req, payload, tries, cb);
      }
    }

    return cb();
  });
```

In this function, it is shown at res.cookie

```
sendEvent(req, payload, 1, function (err, response) {
    if (err) {
      req.mtShout.error('[ANALYTICS ERROR]', err);
    }
    if (!_.get(req, ['currentClient','oneTrust', 'enabled']) ||
      (
        _.get(req, ['optanonConsent', 'groups']) &&
        req.optanonConsent.groups.indexOf(req.currentClient.oneTrust.categories.performance + ':1') > -1
      )
    ) {
      res.cookie(COOKIE_NAME, payload.session_id, {
        maxAge: config.server.raCookieMaxAge,
        secure: secureCookieFlag,
        httpOnly: true
      });
    }
    req.raSession = payload.session_id;
  });
```